# Run a sql (update) after 12 hours after the user login. Woocommerce users

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, sql

How can I Run a sql (update) after 12 hours after the user login (for Woocommerce users)

After 12 hours after a user login, I want to run a sql/ function to update a value in the database.

To set a value to '0' again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (this code has not been testedt).

```
function schedule_sql_command($user_login, $user) { 
  // 12 hours in seconds.
  $from_now = 12 * 60 * 60;
  // schedule a call to a custom hook passing in the user's ID
  wp_schedule_single_event(time() + $from_now, 'run_sql_command', array( $user->ID) );
}

// this is the custom hook that takes the user_id as a param
function run_sql_command($user_id) { 
 global $wpdb;
 $wpdb->query("Your query here using $user_id"); 
}
// Hook when user logs in
add_action( 'wp_login', 'schedule_sql_command') ;
```

Comment: It doesn't work even though it seems a good solution. The code breaks up

Comment: I think `do_action()` is the problem. Should write `add_action()`. but it doesn't change the vlaue in the databse anway :(

Comment: Yeah it should have been `add_action()`    code updated.  Try using the crontrol plugin to see scheduled events